# Passing multiple parameter to DELETE request c# web API

Tags: c#, rest, parameters, asp.net-web-api2, http-delete

My question is how can I pass multiple parameter to DELETE request.

My controller class as follow,

```
namespace MYAPI1.Controllers
{
    public class TaskController : ApiController
    {
        // DELETE: api/Task/5
        [Route("api/Task/id1/id2/{id3}")]
        public void Delete(int id,int id2, string id3)
        {
            TaskPersistent tp = new TaskPersistent();
            tp.deleteTask(id,id2,id3);
        }
    }
}
```

TaskPersistent.class as follow,

```
public class TaskPersistent
{
    public void deleteTask(int id, int id2, string id3)
    {

        try
        {
            string sqlString = "DELETE from devproj WHERE (DeveloperID, ProjectID, WorkDate) =  VALUES ('" + id + "', '" + id2 + "', '" + id3 + "');";
            MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(sqlString, conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            long x = cmd.LastInsertedId;

        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }

    }

}
```

I try to consume this using postman like this,`http://localhost:10927/api/Task?id1=1&id2=5&id3="2018-03-14"`
but which not working, please help me to solve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are good ways to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: @mjwills Is this same as that question? lol

Comment: `VALUES ('" + id + "', '" + id2 + "', '" + id3 + "');"` You have your current bug. And it is bad. But it is **nothing** compared to the security hole that code is introducing. Hence the link I suggested.

Comment: @mjwills Ok thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following

```
    [Route("api/Task/{id:int}/{id2:int}/{id3}")]
    public void Delete(int id,int id2, string id3)
    {
        TaskPersistent tp = new TaskPersistent();
        tp.deleteTask(id,id2,id3);
    }
```

Call it via:   http://localhost:10927/api/Task/1/2/"2018-03-14"

--- OR ---

```
    [Route("api/Task")]
    public void Delete(int id,int id2, string id3)
    {
        TaskPersistent tp = new TaskPersistent();
        tp.deleteTask(id,id2,id3);
    }
```

Call it via:   http://localhost:10927/api/Task?id=1&id2=2&id3="2018-03-14"

Comment: when is use routing as `[Route("api/Task/{id1:int}/{id2:int}/{id3:string}")]` this following Exception thrown: `System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Web.Http.dll` in **Global.asax.cs** could you explain why

Comment: The inline constraint resolver of type 'DefaultInlineConstraintResolver' was unable to resolve the following inline constraint: 'string'.

Comment: My bad, you need to take ":string" off of id3.  string is the default type and it dosn't like being told what it already is

Comment: how is the behaviour when passing a guid? do I just mark the parameter in the route as {paramName:guid}?

Answer (score 3):

Try passing a view model:

```
public class YourViewModel {
     public int Id1 { get; set;} 
     public int Id2 { get; set;} 
     public string Id3 { get; set;} 

   }
```

Then

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Task")]
 public void Delete([FromBody] YourViewModel model)
 {
     TaskPersistent tp = new TaskPersistent();
     tp.deleteTask(model.Id1, model.Id2, model.Id3);
 }
```

In this way you don't have to specify the parameters in the query string. But you have to ensure that the request header has:

```
'Content-Type: application/json'
```

**Update:**
In case you need to give it a try, this is how you need to call it from the client side in case you are using JQuery:

```
var myModel= { Id1:1, Id2:11 Id3:"test" }
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:10927/api/Task',
    data: JSON.stringify(myModel),
    contentType: 'application/json;',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){  }
});
```

Comment: I already tried this way too and used model class. but my problem is not solved

Comment: You need to show how are you posting data and what's happening in this case.

Comment: Ok then, how to implement **deleteTask** method in TaskPersistent.class

Answer (score -1):

```
[HttpDelete]
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(List<string> ids)
{
  await _mapService.RemoveAsync(ids);
  var ret = CreatedAtAction(nameof(Delete), new { ids = ids }, ids);

  return ret;
}

Curl

curl -X 'DELETE' \
  'https://localhost:44307/api/Map' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '[
  "623b35de9f6cedc3a22f7b37",
"623b35de9f6cedc3a22f7b38"
]'

Response body
Download
[
  "623b35de9f6cedc3a22f7b37",
  "623b35de9f6cedc3a22f7b38"
]
Response headers
 content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
 date: Wed,23 Mar 2022 15:00:39 GMT 
 location: https://localhost:44307/api/Map?ids=623b35de9f6cedc3a22f7b37&ids=623b35de9f6cedc3a22f7b38 
 server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 
 x-powered-by: ASP.NET
```